# Error 2026:tls/ssl error:Sslv3 alert handshake failure

Tags: ssl, mariadb, ssl-certificate, centos7, lets-encrypt

I'm using centos 7 and mariadb 10.6. I'm trying to configure mariadb ssl between client and server using let's encrypt certificate. Using the below command i have generated certificate

```
Certbot certonly -d domain1 -d domain2
```

Then i copied it to my folders and configured /etc/my.cnf like below

```
[mariadb]
ssl_cert=/etc/my.cnf.d/server/fullchain.pem
ssl_key=/etc/my.cnf.d/server/privkey.pem
[client-mariadb]
ssl_cert=/etc/my.cnf.d/client/fullchain.pem
ssl_key=/etc/my.cnf.d/client/privkey prm
```

After this i restarted mariadb using

```
service mariadb restart
```

But when I'm trying to login to mariadb terminal it showing sslv3 alert handshake failure.

What is causing this issue. How to resolve it? Could you please help

Comment: Do you use mariadb command line client to connect to the server?

Comment: @GeorgRichter hi, Yes i use mariadb -u root -p command then login to terminal. But after providing the password it is giving sslv3 alert handshake failure error.

Comment: @GeorgRichter also i have provided 444 file permission for fullchain.pem and 600 permission for privkey. Pem. For the folder i have given mysql privilege.

Comment: @Vijay  Is the error like : ERROR 2026 (HY000): TLS/SSL error: sslv3 alert handshake failure

Comment: @Vishnu yes same error.